# How does one plot $z=(-2)^{3/5}$?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How does one plot $z=(-2)^{3/5}$?

I see in Wolfram Alpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E5%3D-8

But I don't understand how that plot is created.

Comment: What do you know of complex numbers?  In particular, do you know how to plot them in the complex plane?  Do you know of the polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @RossMillikan I know how to plot a complex number $x+iy$. I don't know why I see numerous points for complex number that has only real part.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex numbers a number has five fifth roots.  If we use the polar form, we have $z=re^{i \theta}$ and we want $z^{5}=-8$ so 
$$\left(re^{i \theta}\right)^{5}=-8\\
r^{5}=8\\r=8^{1/5}=2^{3/5}\\ \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{5}=-1\\
5\theta=\pi+2k\pi\\ \theta=\frac \pi 5,\frac {3\pi}5, \frac {5\pi}5, \frac {7\pi}5,\frac {9\pi}5$$
The complex solutions are shown on the page.  You can get approximate values by clicking the box.

Comment: How you know if have five roots?

Comment: $k$ is some integer.  It reflects the fact that rotation of a multiple of $2\pi$ puts you back where you were.  In the complex plane an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial always has $n$ roots if you include multiplicity.  Here we have demonstrated them by finding all the values that can be generated by different $k$.  The $n^{th}$ roots of a complex number always fall on a circle centered on the origin and are equally spaced on it, as here.

Comment: Why is $5 \theta = \pi + 2k \pi$?

Comment: Because the angle of $-1$ is $\pi$

Comment: I don't understand. I understand that angle of $-1$ is $\pi$, but not where $5 \theta=...$ comes from.

Comment: $5\theta$ comes from the previous line, where $(e^{i\theta})^5=e^{5i\theta}$.  The exponential of a pure imaginary is on the unit circle at the angle of the imaginary.  Remember that $e^{i \pi}=-1$, which is what says $-1$ is at angle $\pi$